# My gradient descent for linear regression won't converge

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I've been stuck for hours trying to figure it out why my code for Gradient Descent on Linear Regression won't converge.
tried with really small alphas and really huge iterations, still won't work.

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent
% t to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y) % number of training examples

ST0=0;
ST1=0;

for iter = 1:num_iters
   for i=1:m
       ST0=ST0+((theta(1)+theta(2)*X(i))-y(i));
       ST1=ST1+(((theta(1)+theta(2)*X(i))-y(i)))*X(i,2);
   end

  ST0=ST0/m;
  ST0=ST0*alpha;
  ST1=ST1/m;
  ST1=ST1*alpha;  
  theta(1)=theta(1)-ST0;
  theta(2)=theta(2)-ST1;
    J= computeCost(X, y, theta);

    J_history(iter) = J;


end

end
```

Comment: I suggest testing on a very simple straight line equation "y = ax + b" with a very simple data set like "x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]' and "y=[2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]" as this will make troubleshooting the code much easier. Making the initial parameter values "[1.0, 1.0]" with that data will also help in troubleshooting the code.

Comment: i did with x=[1,2,3] y=[2,4,6] and it didnt converge to global minimum, no meter how much i lowered alpha